# JavaFX.MediaPlayer over HTTPS?

Tags: media-player, javafx-2, javafx

I tried to use MediaPlayer to play back a resource defined an HTTPS url, and it says protocol not supported.

In the API reference they state FILE/HTTP/JAR are supported protocols (HTTPS not mentioned).

Is it possible to somehow use urls via HTTPS? This seems quite a big drawback in my opinion...

Comment: Here's the bug for this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091132?focusedCommentId=13747526

Comment: The HTTPS protocol is finally supported as of 8u72.

Comment: I was using jdk 8u73 and it was not working, but switching up to 8u162 did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed for Java 9, and later backported to Java 8. Java 8 update 91 and later should therefore be working with HTTPS URLs without an issue.

If you're using an old version of Java that doesn't support it, then unfortunately the only option you have is to copy the file over HTTPS to a local temporary file, then play that.