# JavaFX: Use a URL source for audio

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I'm able to host my images on imgur for my javafx project like so:

```
Image circle = new Image("http://imgur.com/7oW7ilC.png");
```

But when I try to do the same for audio files, it doesn't play the sound (no errors)

```
Media sound = new Media("http://enkrypton.github.io/filehost2017/hit.mp3");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Is there a way I can use audio files from a URL the same way I use images?
Note that this is not a HTTP Error 403 since I'm able to load other images I have on my filehost.

Comment: Strange.  I can download the file and play it, but I cannot play it directly from the URL with any software.  *Edit:* Looks like that URL is sending back an HTTP 301 redirect.  That’s probably the reason.

Comment: @VGR Do you have any suggestions on a workaround so I'm able to use a URL source for my audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the sound URL is an `http:` URL, which returns an HTTP 301 response that redirects to an `https:` URL.  This is not considered secure, so Java won’t automatically follow it.  For a full discussion of this, see [URLConnection Doesn't Follow Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect).

The easiest solution is to simply change your URL to use `https:`:

```
Media sound = new Media("https://enkrypton.github.io/filehost2017/hit.mp3");
```

Comment: in fact, i actually originally had it in https: but that gave me the following exception: https://pastebin.com/HhVQKJc8

Comment: Are you using JavaFX 8?  If not, is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: i temp added `System.out.println("javafx.runtime.version: " + System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));` to my code and it returned `javafx.runtime.version: 8.0.66-b33` . So I suppose i am using JavaFX 8.

Comment: seems a fixed bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725473/javafx-mediaplayer-over-https